# Printer Setup Utility gone in Mavericks, how to set default printer in Applescript now?

Tags: applescript, macos, printing

I have some Applescripts that set the default printer using "Printer Setup Utility", that seems gone in Mavericks.

Anyone have an alternative to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AppleScript to execute shell scripts, so you can use:

```
do shell script ("lpoptions -d printername")
```

Replace `printername` with the actual printer name. It may not be exactly as it shows in System Preferences (I think ALL non-alphanumeric characters are replaced with underscores, but I'm not certain) so you can view your list of printers with:

```
lpstat -p
```